# How to suppress "coroutine was never awaited" warning?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

All search results on "coroutine was never awaited" are for people who were either trying to fire-and-forget or actually did forget to await. This is not my case.

I want to use a coroutine the same way I often use generators: I'm creating it here while I have all the variables handy, but I'm not sure yet whether I'll ever need that to be run. Something like:

```
options = {
   'a': async_func_1(..., ...),
   'b': async_func_2(),
   'c': async_func_3(...),
}
```

and elsewhere:

```
appropriate_option = figure_the_option_out(...)
result = await options[appropriate_option]
```

Comment: What about doing `'a': lambda: async_func_1(..., ...)`, etc., then `result = await options[appropriate_option]()`?

Comment: What he said. You *are* creating coroutines which you never await. You shouldn't do that. Only call `async_func_*` if you're actually planning to await to, not just to fill your dictionary.

Comment: Why shouldn't I do that? What's the cost of creating coroutines?

Comment: It's not that it shouldn't be done (only you can really answer that anyways), rather it shouldn't *have* to do be done. I take it you're trying to "more performant"? How much performance is gained by doing such a preemptive optimization? If you gain a lot, then do it, otherwise it's a waste.

Comment: I'm really attempting to optimize for the IDE and the debugging tools helping me avoid bugs by silencing only the specific warnings that I know don't apply. In this particular case I read the warning and I know it's okay, so I want to appease the warning for this particular case only.

Comment: Another use-case to suppress warning: create a function or context manager that conditionally awaits the coroutine passed to its arguments list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)'s comment that you should not create the coroutine object until you are ready to await it is probably the most ideal solution.

But if that isn't practical, you can use `weakref.finalize()` to call the coroutine object's `close()` method just before it is garbage-collected.

```
>python -m asyncio
asyncio REPL 3.9.5 (default, May 18 2021, 14:42:02) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Use "await" directly instead of "asyncio.run()".
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import asyncio
>>> import weakref
>>> async def coro(x):
...     print(x)
...
>>> coro_obj = coro('Hello')
>>> del coro_obj
<console>:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'coro' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
>>> coro_obj = coro('Hello')
>>> _ = weakref.finalize(coro_obj, coro_obj.close)
>>> del coro_obj
>>>
```

Comment: Are there any advantages of `weakref.finalize(coro_obj, coro_obj.close)` over `coroutine.close()`?

Comment: @Nairum By all means if you have the reference to the coroutine at a point when you establish it will never be awaited then just call `coroutine.close()`. The weakref solution is for when it would be inconvenient to write code specifically to handle the case where it never gets awaited and you just want to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 9):

I still haven't found something that can be done at initialization, but I found a solution that can be done after all coroutines are awaited.

```
for coroutine in options.values():
    coroutine.close()
```

This `close()` function will work on all coroutines, whether awaited or not.

Comment: Is `close()` method documented anywhere? I cannot find mentions of it on https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted - this it the proper way I believe. `coroutine.close()` can be called even without awaiting and it's documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#coroutine-objects

Answer (score 4):

This might help

```py
import warnings

...

    def go(self):
        try:
            self.loop.run_until_complete(self.run())
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"  {e}")
        finally:
            with warnings.catch_warnings():
                warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
                self._clean_up()

...
```

where `self._clean_up()` causes the RuntimeWarning

You can suppress warnings temporarily as above. You can read about it more in detail at https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings

Answer (score -2):

You could suppress the warnings by using the `-W` flag in Python.

```
python -W ignore my_script.py
```

Comment: This will suppress *all* warnings, including useful ones